# GeoServer in HTTPS

Tags: geohelm

Has anyone been able to run GeoServer in HTTPS?  I have installed the GeoHelm stack, which worked great until I added a CA with Let’s Encrypt.  Every time now when I try to login to GeoServer, I get an error message that the wrong username and password were entered.  I’ve run the setup up several times and right when HTTPS is enabled is when I can no longer login to GeoServer.

Comment: GeoServer has no problem with running behind https - I usually set it in apache or nginx, I have done it directly in tomcat too.

Comment: Could there be a step I’m missing?  I create the website, GeoServer runs flawlessly and login is no issue.  As soon as I finish the certificate and enable https, I can no longer login.  I’ve tried it with a fresh install as well and used the default login.  Same thing, once https is on, I can no longer  login.  My guess is that the encryption is messing the username and password up.  Because the error I get is that the wrong username and password were entered.

Comment: check the log file to see what's happening, but it's unclear where you are setting https up and what might be happening, but it won't be with GeoServer as it knows nothing about the transport protocil

Comment: Seems to work with a self-signed certificate.